# Linq to entities query with inheritance?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have the following model please see image.

[the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzT3w.png)

I am having problems figuring out how I would be able to get all the type SUV from Cars and doing a Sum of the value.

I tried doing the

```
HelpWithSUVSUM = g.OfType<CarsSUV>()
   .Where(d => d.HasPremium == true && (d.Status == "Sold").Sum(d => d.CarValue)
```

But it threw an error. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var statsModel =  (
            from c in db.Cars
                join s in db.Salesman on c.SalesmanId equals c.ID into sales
            select new { s, sales }
            into data
            group data by new { data.c.ModelName, data.c.Year } into g
            select new MyData
            {
                CarYear = g.Key.Year,
                SomeCount = g.Count(d => (d.c.Status == "Sold"),
                // etc.. a few more counts
                // NOW I need to get all Cars that are SUV and HasPremium and do a Sum the SUV value
                HelpWithSUVSum = ....
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: "DbOfTypeExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument."

Comment: `g` is of type `IGrouping`, which is not in your inheritance hierarchy for `CarsSUV`.

Comment: How do I fix it so I can use the inheritance hierarchy. So confusing haha

Comment: Please, no links to images when there is a text alternative. In this case: the code of the classes. Also, links to external sites are disapproved. Stack Overflow has its own image store.

Comment: Ok sorry, wasn't sure how to use it. Fixed the post.

Comment: Yeah, but not in the way I primarily suggested. The model is unclear and has inaccuracies. Only code is unambiguous. That said, the code you do show isn't correct (`c.ID`). And he question is why you don't use navigation properties an do use TPH. Both a property like `salesman.Cars` and a `car.Type` property instead of an invisible discriminator would make this a lot simpler.